# Towards reconstructing intelligible speech from the human auditory cortex dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, research, biology

Recently I read in the article [Towards reconstructing intelligible speech from the human auditory cortex](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37359-z) that *scientists have learned to transform brainwave into sound*.

Is it possible to find data on which the regression model they mentioned there was performed? Or any other similar data.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37359-z#Sec21 ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin, maybe trouble with my browser, but i can't see ,where it. Is there download link?

Comment: I meant the "Supplementary information" section.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, here only wav sounds and not dataset)

Comment: did you look @ the section titled "data availability"? https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-37359-z#data-availability

Comment: @albert, yes, but corresponding author [NM].  How to find him?

Comment: Perhaps this page: http://naplab.ee.columbia.edu/naplib.html. But it's not availabe now. NM is Nima Mesgarani.

Comment: @StanislavKralin why do you say that it is not available now?

Comment: @albert, I thought their server is down, but it seems they just blocks IP addresses from Russia. Perhaps after [this publication](https://habr.com/ru/post/438508/) which should cause a kind of DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

Some data I have found and that I need and maybe anybody needs:

- [Classifying syllables in Imagined Speech using EEG](https://github.com/manuchopra/imagined-speech)
- [Brain_typing](https://github.com/xiangzhang1015/Brain_typing)

Relative data

- [EEG / ERP data available for free public download](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/fam2data/publicly_available_EEG_data.html)
- [Supporting data for "EEG datasets for motor imagery brain computer interface"](http://gigadb.org/dataset/100295)
- Classification learning and tone-counting: 
  http://www.openfmri.org/dataset/
  https://openneuro.org/datasets/ds000011/versions/00001
- [Synchronized Brainwave Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/berkeley-biosense/synchronized-brainwave-dataset/version/4?almost-there=true&token=CfDJ8LdUzqlsSWBPr4Ce3rb9VL8jFf5C-3CmuodYGvzBaozYaIp6a1WYa9kh9I-q5KrbMpaV5izJc6CTbUe7ikP97Pqkt9OuIpYt2UFHoHCuSGUXkQi5Z2qVRXeWsJmwm6BRFXgb7XZIJOSbrISQgTTW8m4s02PARAuq0b2d2JEE720JCNd1RxXQVrjklOPVo2Py1Fz1kAeBoDnMk-gx5ZuqmOHGIvncDWfit4H4fQVZY9jw8_2RyXLipty0rDEzjCnX8vuJUZqPCWbFDfrRGNxMP3gfeZBI2p6N07XPvH4Yk3E1mizZTcjFY6NVYtaxklbsIKnh7VtzdSZgdTDkEj39tVu4ytGjmG3l6BcRMubwZWYsxczy9A6yefNHw9v2jxgwX3yDawwa6huMy9jILG8v8E6MgfahCZWU8PMxmCAE_qgX6k_S52dFcb3WaYOQRaFXB59xPB3oMIzCM3fW6A0zbg7rRmpKidgU7KLFImIF5Kq744bB117oMspxhNn2LhWHKh-NIJzieE1rpZV2_Mzqo2vD-0lmyjTEhu5MZG-Xf-quhcmFJmC7B0bUeDe_PB6njw#_=_)
- [Downloadable EEG data](https://engineuring.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/downloadable-eeg-data/)
- [A large electroencephalographic motor imagery dataset for electroencephalographic brain computer interfaces](https://figshare.com/collections/A_large_electroencephalographic_motor_imagery_dataset_for_electroencephalographic_brain_computer_interfaces/3917698)
- [EEG-Datasets](https://github.com/meagmohit/EEG-Datasets)